# Unclear how to access keys in Freemarker variable

Tags: freemarker

I apologize upfront for the vagueness of my question.

I'm using a product that has a built-in freemarker template engine onto which they pass various variables. Because of this it's tricky to figure out how to access certain parts. The variable seems to have like hash but has some unexpected behavior.

Ultimately what I want to achieve is to iterate through some of it's keys (or maybe they're children) and run some checks on those.

If I hardcode the variable I use: myvariable.paramater but I can also use myvariable['parameter']

When I run the following script I don't get any recognizable keys:

```
<#list myvariable?keys as parameter >
echo ${parameter}
</#list>
```

The output contains things like:

```
echo class
echo toString
echo $attributes
```

The output is just a bunch of echo none of which I can use with myvariable.
The 'key' $attributes might be the list of keys I'm looking for I just don't know how to access that parameter from within the template.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can find the parameters I'm looking for?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but that "echo" there means nothing to FreeMarker... it's just static text that it will print as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the FreeMarker configuration and on what's the class of the object that you are looking at. If the object is a `Map`, then `?keys` should return its keys, although, many frameworks configure FreeMarker to return the methods and the `Map` keys mixed, in which case you can fall back to using the Java API (like `map.keys()`). If the object is not a `Map`, then usually you will see the list of JavaBean properties mixed with the methods and perhaps of public fields. If you can do `foo.x` yet `"x"` is not in `foo?keys` then maybe there's some tricy Java class behind, like `java.util.Properties` with inheritance, where Java itself doesn't list the inherited keys, yet you can use them if you know their name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. 
The list the `?keys` was giving me was a list om methods than I could run like `myvariable.toString()` for example.
The trick was to find the right method. Going through the list I found a `getProperties` that when I tried to echo it resolved to a `SimpleHash` type. This object allowed me to properly use the `?keys` and gave me what I was looking for.